# Passing value with spaces as cmd parameter to programs

Tags: windows, vbscript

```
strTarget = "C:\My Name\K.jpg"
```

as you can see there is a space in the address which is stored in strTarget, Now I\m trying to pass it to an application, but it won't work because there is space in address :(

```
TargetApp.Run """C:\My App\here.exe"" " & strTarget ,,true
```

if I change strTarget into "C:\MyName\K.jpg" which does not have space it will work.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add double quotes around the image path the same way you did around the executable path:

```
TargetApp.Run """C:\My App\here.exe"" """ & strTarget & """" ,,true
```

I usually recommend using a quoting function for this, because it significantly increases the readability:

```
Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function

app = "C:\My App\here.exe"
img = "C:\My Name\K.jpg"

TargetApp.Run qq(app) & " " & qq(img), 0, True
```