# Escaping spaces in folder path

Tags: vbscript, robocopy

I have a backup script the copies from one server to another via scheduled task.  Most of the folders copy ok.   However, there is one folder that has a space in the name and it blows the whole thing up.

This runs on the destination server (pulls data in).

I've tried various escape patterns, and they all fail.
 (vars are dimmed, code truncated)

```
sArchiveFolder = "D:\Backup\" & year(now) & "-" & month(now) & "-" & day(now) & "\"

sDataFolder = "\\Server\Share\System Library"
sDestFolder = sArchiveFolder & "System Library\"
Call subCopyFolder(fso, objShell, sDataFolder, sDestFolder)



sub subCopyFolder(fso, objShell, sDataFolder, sArchiveFolder)
    dim iCounter, excludedDirs
    if not(fso.folderexists(sArchiveFolder)) then    
         fso.createfolder(sArchiveFolder)

    excludedDirs = " /XD Logs"

    if(right(sDataFolder,7)="Library") then
        'this fails
        'sDataFolder = """"&sDataFolder&""""
        'sArchiveFolder = """"&sArchiveFolder&""""

        'so does this
        'sDataFolder = chr(34)&sDataFolder&chr(34)
        'sArchiveFolder = chr(34)&sArchiveFolder&chr(34)

    end if

    Dim sRoboCopyCommand
    sRoboCopyCommand = "robocopy " & sDataFolder  & " " &  sArchiveFolder &  " /E "& excludedDirs &" /R:5 /W:1 /log+:log.txt"
    objShell.Run (sRoboCopyCommand)

end sub
```

How do I properly escape this?   I also tried putting the literal quotes in the robocopy command line itself and that broke the folders that don't need the quotes too.

As noted in the code, I tried the "4 quotes method" and it does not work within the robocopy command line.

with 4 quotes method:

[image: picture of MsgBox sRoboCopyCommand]
(stripped out private stuff not relevant to issue, ie full paths and other eXcludeD fodlers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing value with spaces as cmd parameter to programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916485/passing-value-with-spaces-as-cmd-parameter-to-programs)

Comment: As noted in the code, I tired that "4 quotes" method, and it does not work within the robocopy command.

Comment: How exactly did it "not work". Your `robocopy` command apparently creates a log: what does it say?

Comment: The log never gets written for that folder call at all, which implies that the variable string `sRoboCopyCommand` is being corrupted at some point.  I put a msgbox around the var, and it looks fine though, attached in post above.

Comment: Did you try running the script outside the scheduled task?

Comment: Yes, I haven't scheduled this code update yet (which includes this new folder).  I'm just double clicking the .vbs file to invoke.  and all non-spaced folders work (that are listed in code before this call).  Everything after the fact fails, even with `on error resume next`.   I placed a msgbox after the robocopy call and it never shows up.  the dos box shows for a split second and closes.  Going to pull out the command and `pause` it.

Comment: `2015/05/07 12:10:55 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Destination Directory D:\Backup\2015-5-7\System Library" \E  \XD Logs \R:5 \W:1 \log+:log.txt\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`    I tried changing the destination directory to a single word and the same error exists.   The Folder DOES get created ahead of time and DOES exist.  And again, all other folders run this same sub and work.  It must be source issue, not destination.

Comment: Hmm... try removing the trailing backslash from both source and destination path.

Comment: Yup, so apparently the `\"` becomes an escape character.  removing trailing slash clears it all.  geeze.   Thanks for the help on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posteriority: apparently trailing backslashes in source or destination path mess up `robocopy`'s parameter handling, so the paths need to be specified without them:

```
sArchiveFolder = "D:\Backup\" & year(now) & "-" & month(now) & "-" & day(now)

sDataFolder = "\\Server\Share\System Library"
sDestFolder = sArchiveFolder & "\System Library"
...
sRoboCopyCommand = "robocopy """ & sDataFolder  & """ """ &  sArchiveFolder & _
                   """ /E " & excludedDirs & " /R:5 /W:1 /log+:log.txt"
objShell.Run sRoboCopyCommand
```

Comment: To be more specific, the trailing slash removal only needs to be made on paths that are literally quoted (due to the space).  Removing the trailing slash from items that are not literally quoted breaks.